# Prime Faces IE7 Z-index problems

Tags: internet-explorer-7, primefaces

I am not having any joy over at the Prime Faces forum on my question about IE7 and was hoping someone here might be able to help.

Basically two problems:

1. IE7 Z-index problem of the modal popup showing on top of the site's logo. (The logo has an absolute position to make it sit on top of the design)
2. The modal window does not open to the right size, it's smaller in IE8 and greater.

Problem here is that I don't have full control of the site. I basically am trying to make things work in the Developer Toolbar and then sending the changes back to the developers.

Here is a video to show the two points of issue as mentioned above.

http://screencast.com/t/aW1ecqIuNi

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post some html code? I'm guessing that you just need to set `postion:relative` on your parent element or possibly the body tag and then set a z-index lower than your dialog z-index.

Comment: Hi Catfish, it's a bit tough to post code as I have no control over it. You can however view the project with developer toolbar in IE here: http://goo.gl/CiucU

Comment: If you have no control over it, how can you make a change to fix it?